# How to fetch value from a list- python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a output saved as below in a variable, my requirement is if user enters name esx1 it should print datastore-46 as output, can anyone please help how it can be done.

{'browser': 'vim.host.DatastoreBrowser:datastoreBrowser-datastore-46', 'name': 'esx1'}, {'browser': 'vim.host.DatastoreBrowser:datastoreBrowser-datastore-24', 'name': 'esx2'}

`val=input("Enter a name")`

user entered: esx1
output should be: datastore-46

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
ip = [{'browser': 'vim.host.DatastoreBrowser:datastoreBrowser-datastore-46', 'name': 'esx1'}, {'browser': 'vim.host.DatastoreBrowser:datastoreBrowser-datastore-24', 'name': 'esx2'}]
val=input("Enter a name")
result = ''.join(i['browser'] for i in ip if i['name']==val).split('-',1)[-1]
```

Comment: Thanks..but got below error-

    result = ''.join(i['browser'] for i in ip if i['name']==val).split('-',1)[-1]
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, vim.host.DatastoreBrowser found